# Images in imageviews are overlapping

Tags: android, xml, layout

I want to display my 3 images into these frames which are transparent inside. but i have used 3 image views to display my pictures inside them. the problem is that they are not coming exact in the frames but they go into next frame as to fill the image view's width and height. here i am attaching my xml file as well as java file. I don't know what to use so that my images fix in them. Masking is the option or something else?

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
       >


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/imgContainer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@+id/recycler_view"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/save_layout">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/leftside"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="matrix" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/middle"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/leftside"
                android:scaleType="matrix" />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/rightside"
                android:layout_width="128dp"
                android:layout_height="320dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:scaleType="matrix" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgframe"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />


        </RelativeLayout>


    </RelativeLayout>


import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.DiskCacheStrategy;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import droidninja.filepicker.FilePickerBuilder;
import droidninja.filepicker.FilePickerConst;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.AppSettingsDialog;
import pub.devrel.easypermissions.EasyPermissions;

public class DisplayActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements EasyPermissions.PermissionCallbacks {
    public static final int RC_WRITE_PERMISSION = 12;
    static final int NONE = 0;
    static final int DRAG = 1;
    static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private static final int EXTERNAL_CAMERA_PERMISSION_CONSTANT = 100;
    protected static InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;
    RecyclerView horizontal_recycler_view;
    HorizontalAdapter horizontalAdapter;
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    PointF startPoint = new PointF();
    PointF midPoint = new PointF();
    float oldDist = 1f;
    int mode = NONE;
    ImageView leftside, rightside, middleside;

    String currentImage = "";
    RelativeLayout imgContainer;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder;
    ImageView mImage;
    File sdImageMainDirectory;
    int click = 0;
    ArrayList<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Spacecraft> spacecrafts = new ArrayList<>();
    private float[] lastEvent = null;
    private float d = 0f;
    private float newRot = 0f;
    private int REQUEST_CAMERA = 1, SELECT_FILE = 5;
    private String userChoosenTask;
    private boolean left, right, middle = false;
    private int leftClickCount = 0;
    private int rightClickCount = 0;
    private int middleClickCount = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display);
        InterstitialAdmob();

        horizontal_recycler_view = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
        horizontalAdapter = new HorizontalAdapter(Utils.sThumbs, this);

        LinearLayoutManager horizontalLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(DisplayActivity.this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
        horizontal_recycler_view.setLayoutManager(horizontalLayoutManager);
        horizontal_recycler_view.setAdapter(horizontalAdapter);


        Bundle bdl = getIntent().getExtras();
        int index = bdl.getInt("Index");
        mImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgframe);
        mImage.setImageResource(Utils.mThumbIds[index]);


        imgContainer = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.imgContainer);

        leftside = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.leftside);
        rightside = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rightside);
        middleside = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.middle);


        rightside.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                ImageView rightside = (ImageView) v;
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(midPoint, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                        lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                        lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                        lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                        d = rotation(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (rightClickCount == 0) {


                            right = true;
                            left = false;

                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            // ...
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
                                    event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x,
                                        midPoint.y);
                            }
                            if (lastEvent != null) {
                                newRot = rotation(event);
                                float r = newRot - d;
                                matrix.postRotate(r, rightside.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                                        rightside.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

                rightside.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                return true;
            }

            private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
                double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
                double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
                double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

                return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
            }

            @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });


        middleside.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                ImageView middleside = (ImageView) v;
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(midPoint, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                        lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                        lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                        lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                        d = rotation(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (middleClickCount == 0) {


                            right = false;
                            left = false;
                            middle = true;

                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                        mode = NONE;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            // ...
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
                                    event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x,
                                        midPoint.y);
                            }
                            if (lastEvent != null) {
                                newRot = rotation(event);
                                float r = newRot - d;
                                matrix.postRotate(r, middleside.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                                        middleside.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                }

                middleside.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                return true;
            }

            private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
                double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
                double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
                double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

                return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
            }

            @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });


        leftside.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {


                ImageView leftside = (ImageView) v;
                switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                        startPoint.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                        mode = DRAG;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                        oldDist = spacing(event);
                        if (oldDist > 10f) {
                            savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                            midPoint(midPoint, event);
                            mode = ZOOM;
                        }
                        lastEvent = new float[4];
                        lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                        lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                        lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                        lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                        d = rotation(event);
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        if (leftClickCount == 0) {

                            left = true;
                            right = false;

                        }
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                        mode = NONE;
                        lastEvent = null;
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:

                        if (mode == DRAG) {
                            // ...
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - startPoint.x,
                                    event.getY() - startPoint.y);
                        } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                            float newDist = spacing(event);
                            matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                            if (newDist > 10f) {
                                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, midPoint.x,
                                        midPoint.y);
                            }
                            if (lastEvent != null) {
                                newRot = rotation(event);
                                float r = newRot - d;
                                matrix.postRotate(r, leftside.getMeasuredWidth() / 2,
                                        leftside.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                            }
                        }

                        break;
                }

                leftside.setImageMatrix(matrix);

                return true;
            }

            private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
                double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
                double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
                double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);

                return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
            }

            @SuppressLint("FloatMath")
            private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
                return (float) Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            }

            private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
                float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
                float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
                point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
            }
        });


    }








    public Bitmap takeSnap() {
        imgContainer.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        imgContainer.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bitmap = imgContainer.getDrawingCache();
        return bitmap;
    }



    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        switch (requestCode) {
            case FilePickerConst.REQUEST_CODE:

                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                    filePaths = data.getStringArrayListExtra(FilePickerConst.KEY_SELECTED_PHOTOS);

                    Spacecraft s;
                    try {
                        for (String path : filePaths) {
                            s = new Spacecraft();
                            s.setUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(path)));
                            spacecrafts.add(s);
                        }
                        setImages();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
                }
        }

    }

    private void setImages() {
        Picasso.with(this).load(spacecrafts.get(0).getUri()).into(leftside);
        Picasso.with(this).load(spacecrafts.get(1).getUri()).into(middleside);
        Picasso.with(this).load(spacecrafts.get(2).getUri()).into(rightside);

    }


    public class HorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {


        Integer[] horizontalList;
        Context context;


        public HorizontalAdapter(Integer[] horizontalList, Activity context) {
            this.horizontalList = horizontalList;
            this.context = context;
        }

        @Override
        public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);
            return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {


            holder.imageView.setImageResource(horizontalList[position]);


        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return horizontalList.length;
        }

        public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            ImageView imageView;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                imageView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_image);



                        }

          mImage.setImageResource(Utils.mThumbIds[getAdapterPosition()]);


                        takeSnap();



                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Give more information about your code , about layouts ...

Comment: try to use linear layout by set orientation **horizontal**

Comment: paste your design xml code here

Comment: Use LinearLayout as Karthik said and also you can set weight of imageviews to same value to have them even widths. If you wish to use RelativeLayout drag imageview2 to right side of image1 to have imageview2   android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/Image_1"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:id="@+id/Image_2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```